# Python Pandas Data Frame: One column contains special HTML spcial characters such as &amp; &lt; Is there a way to remove them?

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

[image: example dataframe]

[image]

I am only showing an example here. Is there a way to remove all of the special characters? (eg. not just `"&amp;" and "&lt;"` shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following would work with only one pass through the text

```
re.sub("&[a-zA-Z]+?;","",corpus_of_text)
```

in a dataframe i think its just  (I think...)

```
cleaned_values = df['column2'].str.replace(re.compile("&[a-zA-Z]+?;"),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

found this https://gist.github.com/codeboy/5487eeb1c551d59e2366 which does slightly more than you're asking, so i modified it to this:

```
import re

def parse_text(text, patterns=None): 
    """ 
    modified from above github gist
    delete all HTML entities 
    :param text (str): given text 
    :param patterns (dict): patterns for re.sub 
    :return str: final text 
    """ 
    base_patterns = {"&[rl]dquo;": "", 
                     "&[rl]squo;": "", 
                     "&nbsp;": "", 
                      "&amp;": ""} 
    patterns = patterns or base_patterns 
     
    final_text = text 
    for pattern, repl in patterns.items(): 
        final_text = re.sub(pattern, repl, final_text) 
    return final_text
```

you can call it like this, assigning to a new column so you can compare the result to the original string:

```
df["column3"] = df["column2"].apply(parse_text)
```

please note that the `patterns` variable is probably not complete, and you may have to augment it based on what you have in your escaped HTML.

Comment: this could be pretty slow for big text or a big list of patterns

Comment: @JoranBeasley: true, good point. thank you for adding that.